# How to attach id of table to request in laravel while validating?

Tags: laravel, laravel-request

The Laravel form request validator runs a query when using exists.

```
'item_name'=>'required|exists:items,name'
```

After validating for saving data I need to again run the same query and find items.id
Can I prevent this extra query?
I'm using validation for 1000 rows in csv. Please suggest other optimization techniques if any.

Comment: With a custom validator you can run a single query to get all existing item_names and save it to a collection in a class property. you will need to add the new names on the go to the collection.

Comment: If you're validating CSV rows then maybe you should avoid using the `exists` rule and instead gather all names at the end and query the database in a single query to get all matching names and existing ids and manually reject rows that you can't find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used collection of all items inside FormRequest constructor.
Item::all();
this would get huge amount of data but would prevent running query n times.

Inside witValidator function

```
public function withValidator(Validator $validator,Array $row): Validator
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator)use($row) {
       
        $exists = $this->item_collection->firstWhere('id',$this->id);
       if(!$exists){
          $validator->errors()->add('id','id not found');
       }
    });
}
```